# Sum expression in report Buildr

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder, rdl

I got this expression

```
=iIF(Isnothing(Fields!Saldo_contable.Value) or (Fields!Saldo_contable.Value)<0,0,Fields!Saldo_contable.Value)
```

That works fine, I need to sum the result of the whole expression

```
=sum(iif(Isnothing(Fields!Saldo_contable.Value) or (Fields!Saldo_contable.Value)<0,0,Fields!Saldo_contable.Value)),
```

i dont get an actual error but the field just show the result: #Error,

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If Saldo_contable is not an integer, you need to use CDEC(0) for the zero value (2nd argument) of the IIF.

```
=SUM(IIF(Isnothing(Fields!Saldo_contable.Value) or (Fields!Saldo_contable.Value) < 0, CDEC(0), Fields!Saldo_contable.Value))
```

SUMming values like 0 and 2.25 results in a *Can't sum different data type* error.

Your detail line works because it isn't using SUM - just displaying the values.